# query path existance and process results on TRUE

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

The below checks for the existence of registry keys and based on the result of "TRUE" how do I let a script capture it and process it?

example - `$testpath1` will always exist. However `$testpath2, $testpath3` or `$testpath4` may not always exist. Thus the script should process testpath1 only as that returns as true.

However, if `$testpath2` and `$testpath3` exists then the script should process up to `$testpath3` and ignore `$testpath4`

I have the below but the problem is that once it figures out the first statment is true it processes that one only and bypasses all the other statements. I really want the script to go through every statement and the one that contains a false then ignroe that one and process the one before it. I guess a IF ELSE not applicable for something like this - what should I use for this then?

Here is the code and the result of the below is:

RESULT:  `1 is true`

However `$testpath1` AND `$testpath2` EXIST...

```
$CommunityName = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath} | where-object {$_.PSChildName } | Foreach-Object {$_.PSChildName}

$testpath1 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 1) -ne $null 2>$null
$testpath2 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 2) -ne $null 2>$null
$testpath3 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 3) -ne $null 2>$null
$testpath4 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 4) -ne $null 2>$null

if ($testpath1 -eq 'TRUE')
{
Write-Host "1 is true"
}
elseif ($testpath1 -eq 'TRUE' -and $testpath2 -eq 'TRUE')
{
Write-Host "1 and 2 is true"
}
elseif ($testpath1 -eq 'TRUE' -and $testpath2 -eq 'TRUE' -and $testpath3 -eq 'TRUE')
{
Write-Host "1 and 2 and 3 are true"
}
elseif ($testpath1 -eq 'TRUE' -and $testpath2 -eq 'TRUE' -and $testpath3 -eq 'TRUE' -and $testpath4 -eq 'TRUE')
{
Write-Host "1 and 2 and 3 and 4 are true"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this can works depends of your needs:

```
 $a = $testpath1, $testpath2 , $testpath3 , $testpath4 # convert your true/false results in an array
$s = "" # empty string
$i = 1 # a simple variable as index
foreach ($b in $a)
 {
   if ($b -ne $true ) 
   { 
     break
   } 

   $s += "$i " # if true add index in string
   $i++
}

"$($s)is/are true" #output the result
```

Comment: thanks for that - I am trying to apply it to my script but am stuck - Would I still apply the $testpath1 - $testpath4 and then fill $a to those results? so would $a look like: $a = "$testpath1", "$testpath2"..etc?

Comment: what can I say!!! I owe you a million donuts! Thanks a lot - works wonders! Many thanks!

Comment: in fact - I still have a question that needs to be answered..I will ask on another thread that is related to this problem.